# Python edit form data prior to django validation

Tags: python, django, forms, validation, django-forms

I'm fairly new to python and have been searching for awhile to find how I can edit form data BEFORE all the standard python form/field validators do their magic.

I have a model form with an IntegerField which I'd like to remove the "$" and commas from (using some sort of custom validation), then let the normal to_python() validate() etc do their thing.

My code is below - any help would be much appreciated!

forms.py

```
class BuyerSettingsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    total_offer_limit = forms.IntegerField(required=False, max_value=10000000, min_value=0)

    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BuyerSettingsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)    

    class Meta:
        model = Buyer
        fields = ['total_offer_limit']

    def save(self, commit=True):
        profile = super(BuyerSettingsForm, self).save(commit=commit)
        profile.total_offer_limit = self.cleaned_data['total_offer_limit']
        profile.save()
        return profile
```

views.py

```
class SettingsPreferences(LoginRequiredMixin, BuyerAccessRequiredMixin, BuyerAdminAccessRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    template_name = 'invoicely/buyer/settings/buyer_settings.html'
    form_class = BuyerSettingsForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('settings_preferences')

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.request.user.profile.buyer

    def get_initial(self):
        ctx = super(SettingsPreferences, self).get_initial()
        ctx.update({
            'total_offer_limit': self.object.total_offer_limit,
        })
        return ctx

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(SettingsPreferences, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['request'] = self.request
        return kwargs

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save()
        messages.add_message(self.request, messages.SUCCESS, "Settings successfully updated")
        return super(SettingsPreferences, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: If you are passing `$` and commas in your integer string your would will fail on `to_python` method of `IntegerField`.

Comment: Yes I know it fails. That's why I want to remove them before it goes to to_python. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are already overloaded `get_form_kwargs` you can do this. This is data which your form will be initialized with. So we can edit it before its initialization.

```
class SettingsPreferences(LoginRequiredMixin, BuyerAccessRequiredMixin, BuyerAdminAccessRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    ...

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(SettingsPreferences, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs = copy.deepcopy(kwargs)
        kwargs['request'] = self.request
        if self.request.method in ('POST', 'PUT'):
            # here put your data editing code
            kwargs['data']['total_offer_limit'] = int(kwargs['data']['total_offer_limit'].strip().replace('$', ''))
        return kwargs
```

Comment: Hi, I actually tried this already but the problem is, kwargs is immutable so I can't change it in the get_form_kwargs method. I then tried to make a mutable copy of kwargs and return the copy but struggled to get it to work...? Any thoughts?

Comment: @PhillipWatts did you copy using `deepcopy`?